# Select 'F1 Packages' option after the page is loaded

Tags: php, jquery

```
<select name="select-your-sporting-event" id="select-your-sporting-event" class="select">
    <option>-------------</option>
    <option>Cricket Packages @ Lords</option>
    <option>Football Packages</option>
    <option>F1 Packages</option>
    <option>Moto GP Packages</option>
    <option>Golf Packages</option>
    <option>Tennis Packages</option>
    <option>Footbal World Cup 2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: better add value to all the options

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() { // when DOM is ready
    // using 'val' method
    $('#select-your-sporting-event').val('F1 Packages');
    // using 'prop' method
    $('#select-your-sporting-event option:contains(F1 Packages)').prop('selected', true);
    // using 'eq' method
    $('#select-your-sporting-event option').eq(3).prop('selected', true);
})
```

[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) | [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) | [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)